# Relativistic quantum field theory

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Let $\psi(x)$ be solution of Dirac equation $$ (\gamma^\mu\Pi_\mu-mc) \psi(x)=0 $$ where $\Pi_\mu=i\partial_\mu-eA_\mu$ is momentum operator in present electromagnetic field . We consider tow operators 
$$ P_1=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad ,\quad P_2=\frac{1}{2}$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$
 where verify $P_1+P_2=1$ and $P_2\gamma^\mu=\gamma^\mu P_1$ . If we put $\psi_2=P_1\psi$ and $\psi_1=P_1\psi$, and we write $\psi(x)$ as form $\psi=\begin{pmatrix} \chi\\ \phi \end{pmatrix}$, then we observe that $\psi_1=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \chi+\phi\\ \chi+\phi \end{pmatrix}$

My question, what is Explanation of this result?

Comment: What is so surprising about 
$ \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \chi\\ \phi \end{pmatrix}  
= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \chi+\phi\\ \chi+\phi \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: My guess is that the OP wants to know what is the *significance* of these operators.

Comment: Thomas Fritsch,  Note that two component of $\psi_1$ are equal, what is physical mean of this?